# SQL php Select priority

Tags: php, sql

If I have 2 type of data in a table, which is either ID1 or ID2 empty, how can I select the rows that ID1 is not empty and also is the latest inserted row first , then follow by the data with ID2 not empty?

Example:

```
 Data | ID1 | ID2

 1    | ok  | 

 2    |     |  ok

 3    | ok  |
```

and returns:

```
Data | ID1 | ID2

 3   | ok  |

 1   | ok  | 

 2   |     |  ok
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDERBY ID1 DESC, ID2 DESC
```

Comment: `ORDER BY ID1 DESC, ID2 DESC`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer , how if I wish to let the the data order by the latest inserted id as well ? sorry I forget to mentioned this in my question , my apologize.

Comment: just add ",Data DESC" to the end of the order by

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDERBY ID1 DESC, ID2
```

Answer (score 1):

If ID1 and ID2 are 'ok' or empty then Mahmoud's answer is correct. If not, say its an ID from another table then you can do this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
ORDER BY ID1='' DESC, ID2='' DESC, Data DESC
```

Comment: Yes Mahmoud's answer works , and thanks for your assist as well.